# как отправить pdf-файл через телебот?

Tags: python, telebot

с этим кодом не получается

```
file = open('конспект.pdf', 'r')
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, file)
```

Comment: замените `file = open('конспект.pdf', 'r')` на `file = open('конспект.pdf', 'rb')`

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо!